# How can i get the records that contain a single quotation mark in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i get the records that contain a single quotation mark in SQL Server?

The following as you guess, is not valid, but you get the point

```
SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [People] WHERE Name LIKE '%'%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double single quote is interpreted as a single quote in a string:

```
SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [People] WHERE Name LIKE '%''%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quote

```
SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [People] WHERE Name LIKE '%''%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, the % are under 3 `'` (like `'%'%'`). They should be under 4.

```
SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [People] WHERE Name LIKE '%''%'
```

The `%` are now escaped in this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the escape code as others have mentioned or you can use the char code 39, where CHAR(39) is '.

```
SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [People] WHERE Name LIKE '%' + CHAR(39) + '%'
```